# Input parameter to jtable executing method

Tags: jquery-jtable

I'm developing an asp.net application and get this problem: I want load data with some search condition (from user's input) and shows it in one gird (jTable). But in aspx.cs file, the method that launch the query is statis:

```
"public static object StudentList(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)"
```

so I can't input search condition in it. I wonder I can do it somewhere in aspx file:

```
            title: 'The Student List',
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC', //Set default sorting
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Demo/StudentList',
            deleteAction: '/Demo/DeleteStudent',
            updateAction: '/Demo/UpdateStudent',
            createAction: '/Demo/CreateStudent'
        },
```

Great thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion
set search option in string in webmethod of   "/Demo/StudentList" ,or for dynamic set start up search  options in  any .net control to "http.session" variable and 
access it in Web method .
Hopes this helps.